# SQL Insert bad performance in specific table

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a python app that insert records to a azure sql server database, the app insert records to several tables and it works fine except for one specific table that takes 3 minutes to insert 11,000 records. For other tables in the same database insert 11,000 records take a few seconds.

For all tables insert we use cursor.executemany and use exactly the same process. We have carefully reviewed the code in order to find some bug but the python code is very simple son we think the problem could be on the table keys that we use.
This is the python code :

```
#df_puntaje is a dataframe containing records to be inserted
tuples = df_puntaje.to_records(index=False).tolist()
query = "INSERT INTO Puntaje VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
try:
    cursor.executemany(query, tuples)
    add_success = True
    add_result = ''
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    add_success = False
    add_result = e
```

The table has only nine columns, fields 1-6 are key fields

[table design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FidBO.png)

do you think that the key fields can be a problem? can you give some advice?

we have deleted the table from the database and created again and the performance is still the same

we have changed the way we insert the records and nothing happens

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll get better answers if you can [edit] your question and add more details, like any triggers and keys on your tables. Please check [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Any triggers, foreign keys, indexed views that could slow down inserts? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Let us now more about the designer of the table and error you get when you try to insert. Also you can check the SQL profiler for listening to the events happening back there.